# How one can solves an equation of the form: $ap_{n}+bn=c$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

My question is: How can one solve an equation of the form:

$$ap_{n}+bn=c$$
where $p_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ prime number, $a,b$ and $c$ are integers.

Comment: $p_n\simeq n\ln n$.

Comment: @lucian: I am seeking an exact solution

Comment: Are a,b,c positive?

Comment: @mahdokht: Not necessary

Comment: @ZE1: Seek and you shall find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k,m$ be any two integers and $r$ the remainder of $m/n$. Then rearranging your equation into $$a=\frac{c-bn}{p_n} $$ we see that all the triplets of solutions are of the form $(a,b,c)=\left(k,\displaystyle \frac{m-r}{n}, m-r+k p_n\right).$

This should be the best you will get, if you refute approximations.